# App crashes in iOS 5 in iPad and works fine in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, crittercism

I have Crittercism in my app. I created a copy of this app to ugrade to next version. But it crashes before it enters `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. But the previous version of app is working fine. In case I remove the Crittercism in the current then it works fine. Crittercism version is `libCrittercism_v4_1_2.a`. I have no clue about the error. Please help.

Screenshot of error:

[image]

It works fine in iOS 6 and 7. I have enabled zombie and added All Exceptions breakpoint but still no log at all. It just shows the splash screen and crashes.

Comment: did you use any unsupported methods. any available higher level version method used in ios5

Comment: `autoLayout` is not enabled??

Comment: it doesnot enter appdidifinishlaunching and i have disabled autolayout... @iDev

Comment: did you tried with instruments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend upgrading the Crittercism library if you can to a newer version.

If you look at the release notes here:

https://gitlab.recatch.tv/modules-ios/crittercism-ios-sdk/blame/1a167a6c9bd72fe002175680fbeb88d0b1cdafda/release_notes.txt

You can see that there were some changes regarding deployment target in the version you are using. Try to upgrade to a newer version (latest if you can) and see if this corrects your issue.

Good Luck!